# Do a dependency REST service check before liquibase scripts run in a Sprint Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I'd like to do a simple GET call before Liquibase runs it's db scripts in my project (for a dependency check).  I have the GET call encapsulated in a method in one of my service implementations that I'd like to use.

I could call the method in main before

`SpringApplication.run(RESTApplication.class, args);`

But the problem there is that Spring boot has yet to boot.  If I use ApplicationRunner, liquibase has already ran its scripts.   I'm looking for a good pick off point of when Spring starts up but before Liquibase does it's script sequence that I can hook in to.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: What about running it inside custom autoconfiguration class that is annotated with `@AutoConfigureBefore(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class)`. Or implementing BeanPostProcessor.

Comment: I've done a little research on that but I haven't got anything to go just yet

Answer (score 0):

How about `customPrecondition`? You can call a Java class in them and do whatever you need to do.

```
<customPrecondition className="com.example.CustomTableCheck">
    <param name="tableName" value="our_table"/>
    <param name="count" value="42"/>
</customPrecondition>
```

Check out `customPrecondition` section [preconditions article](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html).